# When I resize browsers window, my div gets down to bottom and a big space comes in top

Tags: html, css

When I resize browsers window, my div gets down to bottom and a big space comes in top. I want that my div should remain in center of page even if resize the size of window lesser than size of div. In my school they haven't teach about this but I want to align this div in center of page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CSS centering Done Right.</title>

<style>

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body, .m {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.m {
    opacity:1;
    font-size: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    /*styling>>*/
    background-color: #8F1C10;
}
.m::before {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.m>div {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 19px;
    margin: 20px;
    max-width: 320px;
    min-height: 20px;
    min-width: 300px;
    padding: 14px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*styling*/
    color:white;
    background-color: #140A08;
    outline:none;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<title>CSS centering Done Right.</title>
<div class="m">
    <div contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, enim, possimus, voluptates, quia voluptatibus voluptas eum quaerat iure aperiam asperiores debitis fuga itaque quibusdam a ad odio assumenda iusto voluptatem.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem, ex quia consequatur quae quasi amet veniam est quas error quos perferendis ducimus non similique in soluta magnam dolore molestias veritatis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate, doloremque iste magni in eveniet ipsa odio mollitia eligendi magnam placeat aliquam hic reprehenderit reiciendis itaque assumenda ratione delectus. Alias, quis.</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`margin: auto;` is what you need. Try this:

```
<style>

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/*html, body, .m {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}*/
.m {
    opacity:1;
    font-size: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    /*styling>>*/
    background-color: #8F1C10;
}
.m::before {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.m>div {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 19px;
    margin: 20px;
    max-width: 320px;
    min-height: 20px;
    min-width: 300px;
    padding: 14px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*styling*/
    color:white;
    background-color: #140A08;
    outline:none;
}

</style>
```

Comment: @Plasha If this worked for you don't forget to accept the answer so it can be found easier in the future by people with the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I am just a beginner that's why I am not able to click on that mark, Later I will click that mark and will accept all questions.